# Python lock behaviour with continue

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Suppose I have the following code

```
import threading

def something_with_i(i):
    return i == 3

my_lock = threading.Lock()
for i in range(10):
    with my_lock:
        if something_with_i(i):
            continue

        # do something that requires my_lock
```

In my own code, the `something_with_i(i)` statement is an if-statement that requires the lock to be acquired (it reads the values of a dict).
It is unclear to me whether `my_lock` will be released when `i == 3`. Do I have to release it manually or not?

Comment: "# do something that requires my_lock" still has the lock, is that what your are asking?

Comment: The question is that when ```continue``` is called when ```i == 3```, the code does not get out of the ```with my_lock```. Is the lock released on continue or do I have to call ```my_lock.release()``` before calling ```continue```?

Answer (score 0):

Does this anwser?

```
my_lock = threading.Lock()
    for i in range(10):
        #code here does NOT have the lock
        with my_lock:
            #code here has the lock
            if something_with_i(i):
                continue
            #code here has the lock

        #code here does NOT have the lock
     #code here does NOT have the lock
```